# Using Action mailer for new comment notification rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, comments, actionmailer

I have action mailer setup in my app to send the micropost user a mail whenever a new comment has been made on his micropost.

Here is my code

**comments_controller**

```
def create
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment].permit(:user_id, :body, :micropost_id))
  @comment.micropost = @micropost
  @comment.micropost.user = @micropost.user
  @comment.user = current_user

  if @comment.save
    UserMailer.newcomment_email(@comment).deliver
    @comment.create_activity :create, owner: current_user
    flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
    redirect_to @micropost
  else
    render 'shared/_comment_form'
  end
end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "deppy007@gmail.com"

  def newcomment_email(comment)
    @comment = comment

    mail(to: comment.micropost.user.email, subject: "New Comment Notify")
  end 
end
```

**newcomment_email.html.erb**

```
<%= @comment.user.username %> commented on your post <%= "micropost link?" %>
<p>comment: <%= @comment.body %></p>
```

The code works fine and sends the micropost user a mail noification saying a user commented on your post. how then do i put the micropost link in the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view of your mailer that is `newcomment_email.html.erb` add a `link_to` tag to the comment. For example:

```
<%= link_to 'micropost', micropost_url(@comment.micropost) %>
```

This is just an example. Change it according to your application. It would do the required. Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP is looking for the micropost link, not the comment link. I think you are looking for something like `link_to 'micropost', micropost_url(@comment.micropost)`.

Comment: Yes exactly. That is why I mentioned this is just an example. Change it accordingly. But thanks I would edit it. :)

Comment: @Deep how would i do this for a new follow notification when i have a relationship controller `def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    current_user.follow!(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end  ` and what will be my code for the newfollow_email in my usermailer.rb

Comment: @JustinLicata Please what would my newrelationshipemail.html.erb look like? if i wanted to implement this for a new relationship email(follow). My relationship controller is setup like that above.

Comment: @Day, are you asking what your link would look like in the email if someone were to follow you? Depends...what page do you want the "followee" to go to if someone follows him/her? Wouldn't the link be to the "followers" page?

Comment: @JustinLicata no, there wouldnt be a link atall, just a simple notification email saying user2000 started following you. What would be my code for a new_follow function in the user_Mailer.rb and what will my code be in the newfollow_email.html.erb to show that user2000 started following you. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Please create a new question on S.O. and paste the link here. I can better help you that way.

Answer (score 0):

Then add in your routes.rb

```
Your::Application.routes.draw do

default_url_options :host => "www.example.com"

end
```

Adding your app domain name will redirect the user to the site the micropost exist on

Comment: tanx Deep. Appreciate it